# jTweetsAnywhere for HTML5+PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am able to show #hashtag tweets on my HTML5 based app for mobiles using
http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/demo/Realtime-ticker/

I want to know how can I select a perticular tweet and open another screen?
the tweets are not clickable at the moment.

Comment: The tweets in the example you linked to *are* clickable so you'll need to provide us with infos (code) about your actual situation. Did you have a look at the [gazillion of options in the docs](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/#jta_documentation)?

Comment: I am able to open hyperlinks present in tweets.. but I want to select whole tweet at a time. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I just debugged the JS file and found that whole tweet is coming between <li>... </li> (list) tags. How can I add <a href... /> to individual lists ?

Comment: You can use jQuery to retrieve the href that you want to link for each `.jta-tweet-list-item` and then wrap the whole content in a `<a>` with the right `href`

Comment: can you give some sample? I am new to jQuery :(

Answer (score 0):

In case the plugin does not supply you with the option you are looking for you can always manipulate the DOM yourself to fit your needs. The basic approach for this is demonstrated in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3hFs/2/)**

The jQuery methods you should look up for this are:

- **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**
- **[.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)** or **[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**
- **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Comment: Thanks, I was able to open the tweet in other HTML,
but it works for only static HTML links. If URL changes then I can't do it.

Basically what I want is to show #hashtag tweets on my screen and upon selecting a perticular tweet I want to open it either on twitter client or on device browser. Can you suggest any workaround?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi It depends on how you handle a change (it could be working this way if implemented correctly), but since you seem to have a pretty precise conception of what you want, why don't you use the **[API](https://dev.twitter.com/)** to generate it yourself instead of trying to make a plugin do sth that it wasn't designed for?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi also look up jQuery's `.live()` and `.on()` that are used to bind handlers to elements that are to be created in the future.

Comment: I did it on my own. Hit the URL, get JSON and parse it, add dynamically to <ul> Simple :)
Thanks for helping me out